# Read Linux device input using Wayland and C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, wayland

Is there a way, and if so, how to read device input (/dev/input/event1) using Wayland (or some Wayland wrapper) on Linux? Preferably without creating surfaces.

Comment: Does Wayland do this? According to https://wayland-book.com/seat.html I thought it only dealt with pointers and keyboards - and the only reason it even bothers to do that, is so the compositor can decide where the pointer is, and who gets the keyboard input. To read input from another input device can't you just open the device?

Comment: each device in linux is a file so ready that file as a normal read using file API should be enougth but you will get a raw value you need to convert to some namespace value (keyboard map for example)